# TodoApp - trouble with toggle todo using index

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle a single todo by clicking on li.

I was initially doing this by instituting a state on the Todo class component and modifying it from there, since then i moved the state to the TodoApp component.

I can toggle a single todo by specifying an index number with 1 and it will toggle todo with index 1, however i cannot seem to figure out how to get the index of the clicked li element. My li elements are nested in Todo component.

If i leave the index as **(i) in onClick={() => this.props.toggleTodo(i)}**, i get an error,

**./src/index.js
    Line 12:  'i' is not defined  no-undef**

How can i pass index correctly from my List component to **this.props.toggleTodo()** function  which is being executed in Todo component?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// initializing todo
class Todo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li className="todo" 
                    onClick={() => this.props.toggleTodo(i)}>
                    <span className="btn-completed" style={{color: this.props.completed ? '#99cc99' : '#fafafa'}}>{'\u{2714}'}</span>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: this.props.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{this.props.text}</span>
                    <span className="btn-delete" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.id)} >{'\u{2716}'}</span>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        )
    }
}

// initializing list of todos
const List = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.todos.map((todo, i) => <Todo key={todo.id} onClick={props.onClick} toggleTodo={props.toggleTodo} {...todo}/>)}
    </div>
)

// initializing form
const Form = (props) => (
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" autoFocus required placeholder="Enter Todo..."
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
        />
    </form>
)

// initializing main app
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputText: '',
            todos: []
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
        this.filterTodo = this.filterTodo.bind(this);
        this.toggleAll = this.toggleAll.bind(this);
        this.toggleTodo = this.toggleTodo.bind(this);
    }

    //getting text input value
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({inputText: e.target.value})
    }

    // adding todo
    addTodo = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newTodos = this.state.todos.concat([{text: this.state.inputText, id: Date.now(), completed: false}])
        this.setState({inputText: '', todos: newTodos},
            () => console.log(this.state.todos)
        )
    }

    // filtering todo
    filterTodo = (id) => {
        const filteredTodos = this.state.todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        this.setState({todos: filteredTodos});
    }

    toggleAll = () => {
        const newTodos = this.state.todos;
        newTodos.forEach(todo =>
            todo.completed = !todo.completed
        )
        this.setState({todos: newTodos}, () => console.log(this.state.todos))
    }

    toggleTodo(i) {
        const newTodos = this.state.todos;
        newTodos[i].completed = !newTodos[i].completed
        this.setState({todos: newTodos});
    }

    // rendering view
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form
                    value={this.state.inputText}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    onSubmit={this.addTodo}
                />
                <button onClick={() => this.toggleTodo(1)}>Toggle All</button>
                <List
                    toggle={this.toggleTodo}
                    todos={this.state.todos}
                    onClick={this.filterTodo} 
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
const List = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.todos.map((todo, i) => <Todo key={todo.id} onClick={props.onClick} toggleTodo={() => props.toggle(i)} {...todo}/>)}
    </div>
)
```

Once you do that, you don't need to use i from Todo since the function passed in will already be specific to the specific element in the array.

```
onClick={() => this.props.toggleTodo()}>
```

However, I think it'd be better if you used adapted the toggleTodo method so that it works when you do something like this, but that would require some kind of lookup:

```
onClick={() => this.props.toggleTodo(this.props.id)}
```

EDIT: delete stops working because the `onClick` event is on the `li`. An easy way to get around it is:

```
<li className="todo">
  <span onClick={() => this.props.toggleTodo(i)}>
    <span className="btn-completed" style={{color: this.props.completed ? '#99cc99' : '#fafafa'}}>{'\u{2714}'}</span>
    <span style={{textDecoration: this.props.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{this.props.text}</span>
  </span>
  <span className="btn-delete" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.id)} >{'\u{2716}'}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, but it did not work. I am still getting the same message.

I am exploring the this.prop.id suggestion, i thought about it before.

Comment: Check my edit; I'm pretty sure you are still trying to use `i` in the Todo component.

Comment: Oddly enough, after i got the toggle working,  my delete function stopped firing off. When i click on the btn-delete with onClick={() => this.props.filter(this.props.id)}, delete function does not go off, instead it triggers the toggle, as if ignoring the delete button completely.

Comment: Clicking on the btn-delete is registered, as i can console.log the event.

Comment: I am guess i have 2 onClick events going off on li element and the first one (toggleTodo) is overwriting the filterTodo event. hmmm...

Comment: Does anyone have an answer why onClick={() => this.props.filter(this.props.id)} method is not firing off?

Comment: Good call Kevin. I thought about separating last night and then saw your message the morning. It worked out well and i thank you again. Good day sir.